# Android Bluetooth: Check if remote device needs pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

### Heading

Question is pretty simple, but I doubt it's possible... Is there any way to check if a device needs to be paired?

I'm developing a printer server, some printers need pairing, others do not. I want to create a button to pair on those who need it.

If this isn't possible, how can I check if a device is being paired? The connection is almost always done by a external jar (the driver of the printer, Zebra and Brother). After pairing, it cancels and nothing is printed until you hit the print button again.

Thanks in advance.